# Injecting Views into MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the following problem:
I want to implement MvvM in Best-Practice style so I wanted to implement MvvM like in [this Microsoft-Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUvZ5wVrZ4s). The video takes ~ 1 hour, so I compress the content:

- In the `App.xaml.cs` the `OnStartup`-Event is being overwritten, so that I manually instantiate the MainWindow.
- There's a `MainViewModel` which contains an `ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>` property, the `MainWindow`'s `ItemsControl` is bound to that
- This `MainViewModel` is being instantiated in the `App.xaml.cs` and the `MainWindow`'s `DataContext`is set to this.
- The `MainWindow.xaml` contains a `DataTemplate` which is of type `ViewModelBase` and contains a `MainView`

So, I have several `View`s and `ViewModel`s. But when I place several Views into the `MainView`, only one `View` has filled values (every time the View, which is being placed first in the `MainView.xaml`). I know how it should work:
The Views are all placed in the `MainView` and that `MainView` is shown in the `MainWindow`. Because I set the `MainWindow`'s `DataContext` to the `MainViewModel`, the `MainWindow`'s `ItemsControl` (it's `ItemsSource`) is successfully bound to the `ViewModels` collection of the `MainViewModel`.
But I did never set the `DataContext` of the particular `View`s to their corresponding `ViewModel`. Does Visual Studio automatically bind the corresponding `View`s and `ViewModel`s due to naming convention?

However, only the `View`, which is being placed at first in the `MainView`, has beed filled with values. When I swap the 2nd and the 1. `View`s places in the `XAML`-File, the formerly 2nd `View` works now, but the formerly 1. `View` doesn't have any values filled in anymore. Why is that so?
Of Course i can add specific code, if you want.

---

> But I did never set the DataContext of the particular Views to their corresponding ViewModel. Does Visual Studio automatically bind the corresponding Views and ViewModels due to naming convention?

Now I know, that the `DataTemplate` I set replaces each Instance of `DataType` with an instance of a class I want to be instantiated instead.
So each `View` will be mapped into the MainView (and then the MainView will be mapped into the `MainWindow`) by replacing each of the corresponding 'ViewModel'-instance with it's `View`.

---

One problem solved, and another one pops up:
I have a few styles declared in my `App.xaml` in a `ResourceDictionary`:

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Orange.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And when I add the DataTemplates I need:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OperationViewModel}" x:Key="OpKey">
        <v:OperationView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PlayerViewModel}" x:Key="PKey">
        <v:PlayerView/>
    </DataTemplate>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="MetroStyle">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Orange.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

But then I get kind of a Black-Screen so that the declared style (not the `DataTemplate`) is not being applied. I really dont have much knowledge about `ResourceDictionary`s and the `App.Xaml`, so how can I solve this?

Comment: can you post some code..

Comment: thanks that u wanted to help me, but I found my error.
I'll post an answer soon